# Best way to test for required attributes of a classes __init__ method

Tags: python

I have recently been trying to improve the quality of my code. Towards this goal I want to start writing unit tests and I also am trying to implement things i have read as best practices. I have read that its better to have a class raise exceptions over returning error codes. In the below class I have an **init** method that has dependency requirements based on other arguments being passed in.

Extra details...
The class is from a contracts module that has 3 classes. Contract, ContractLine, ContractCustomer. Contracts can be of two types ('item','vendor') and a contract can also be a group contract. Group contracts are one contract shared amount many customers. A "normal" or non group contract would only have one customer these are all sqlalchemy declarative classes. TimeUserMixin is a class that provides create_time,modify_time, create_user,modify_user to classes where i want to track who made changes and when the changes were made.

My Questions ...

1. Are exceptions the right way to go or is there a "better" way to do
   what I am trying to do.
2. How would I write a tests for this init method?
3. Is it a bad idea to pass in other objects to my classes verse
   passing in the objects id(db id)?

   ```
     class Contract(DeclarativeBase,TimeUserMixin):
           """
           Contract definition.

           This is the customer contract definition.
           Valid contract_type's = 'item'|'vendor'

           """
           __tablename__ = 'contracts'

           contract_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)

           code = Column(Unicode(25),nullable=False)

           description = Column(Unicode(100),nullable=False)

           notes = Column(Unicode())

           is_group_contract = Column(Boolean,nullable=False,default=False)


           contract_type = Column(Unicode(20))

           start_date = Column(Date,nullable=False,default=datetime.date.today)

           end_date = Column(Date,nullable=False)

           reminder_date = Column(Date,nullable=False)

           discount_perc = Column(Numeric(precision=5,scale=4),nullable=False,default=Decimal('0.0'))

           vendor_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('vendors.vendor_id'))

           vendor = relation('Vendor',backref=backref('contracts'),
                             primaryjoin='Contract.vendor_id == Vendor.vendor_id')

           _CONTRACT_TYPES = ('item','vendor')

           @property
           def customer(self):
               """
               Returs Contracts Customer

               Returns the customer object if contract is not a group contract.
               If contract is a group contract raise exception AttributeError

               """
               if self.is_group_contract:
                   raise AttributeError('customer property not avaible on group contracts.')
               return self.customers[0]

           def add_line(self,item,price,min_qty=None):
               """Adds a new contract line to the contract."""
               new_line = ContractLine(self,item,price,min_qty)
               DBSession.add(new_line)

           def add_customer(self,customer):
               """
               Adds a customer to a contract.

               customer -- Customer object
               Raises TypeError if not a group contract and a cutomer is already assigned.

               """
               if not self.is_group_contract and \
                       len(self.customers) > 1:
                   raise TypeError('Contract is not a group contract, and already has a customer assigned.')
               new_customer = ContractCustomer(self,customer)
               DBSession.add(new_customer)

           def __init__(self,code,description,contract_type,
                        start_date,end_date,reminder_date,
                        customer=None,isgroup=False,vendor=None,
                        discount_perc=None):
               """
               Create new contract

               Requires 'contract_type' ['item','vendor']
               if not a group contract requires customer object
               if vendor contract requires vendor object and discount perc

               """
               self.code = code
               self.description = description
               self.contract_type = contract_type
               self.start_date = start_date
               self.end_date = end_date
               self.reminder_date = reminder_date
               if contract_type not in self._CONTRACT_TYPES:
                   raise AttributeError("Valid contract types are 'item' & 'vendor'")
               if isgroup:
                   if customer:
                       raise AttributeError("Group contracts should not have 'customer' passed in")
                   self.is_group_contract = True
               else:
                   if customer:
                       self.add_customer(customer)
                   else:
                       raise AttributeError('Customer required for non group contracts.')
               if contract_type == 'vendor':
                   if vendor and discount_perc:
                       self.vendor = vendor
                       self.discount_perc = discount_perc
                   else:
                       if not vendor:
                           raise AttributeError('Vendor contracts require vendor to be passed in')
                       if not discount_perc:
                           raise AttributeError('Vendor contracts reqire discount_perc(Decimal)')

       class ContractLine(DeclarativeBase,TimeUserMixin):
           """Contract Line Definition"""

           __tablename__ = 'contract_lines'

           line_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)

           min_qty = Column(Integer,default=0,nullable=False)

           contract_price = Column(Numeric(precision=13,scale=2))

           contract_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('contracts.contract_id'),nullable=False)

           contract = relation(Contract,backref=backref('lines'))

           item_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('items.item_id'),nullable=False)

           item = relation('Item',backref=backref('contract_lines'))

           def __init__(self,contract,item,price,min_qty=None):
               """Create new contract line"""
               self.contract = contract
               self.item = item
               self.contract_price = price
               if min_qty:
                   self.min_qty = min_qty

       class ContractCustomer(DeclarativeBase):
           """
           Contract customer definition

           Private class should only be accessed from Contract class

           """
           __tablename__ = 'contract_customers'

           contract_customer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)

           contract_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('contracts.contract_id'),nullable=False)

           contract = relation(Contract,backref=backref('customers'),
                               primaryjoin="ContractCustomer.contract_id == Contract.contract_id")

           customer_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('customers.customer_id'))

           customer = relation(m_ar.Customer,backref=backref('contracts'),
                               primaryjoin='Customer.customer_id==ContractCustomer.customer_id')

           def __init__(self,contract,customer):
               """
               Assigns customer to contract

               contract -- contract object
               customer -- customer object

               """
               self.contract = contract
               self.customer = customer
   ```

Comment: I can't seem to get the code block to format correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You raise odd exceptions. `TypeError` should be raised when the type of an object is incorrect. But you are raising for not following business rules. `AttributeError` should be raised when an attribute is not available, not when you fail validation. You should really either raise your own exceptions or use `ValueError`.

You write unit tests by calling the constructors with different arguments and making sure the correct exceptions get thrown. Where are you having trouble?

`contract_type` is a type parameter. That's a sign that you should really have separate classes for the two types of contracts. You should really have a VendorContract and and ItemContract.

The `customer` thing doesn't feel right. The class basically modifies its interface depending on whether or not its a group contract. Do you actually need to modify the interface? Can you simply say that Contracts with multiple customers are group contracts, and not separately keep track of whether its a group contract? Does other code distinguish between group and non-group contracts? I don't like they way you've done it here, but without more information I'm not sure of a better way.